# PHP ZIP::ExtractTo is not extracting any files

Tags: php, heroku, php-ziparchive

When using the ZipArchive class in PHP, I'm experiencing unexpected behavior. I expect the code block to get the Zip file and extract all of its contents into a directory. I've followed the documentation (Combination of Example #1 and eric at webdeveric dot com's user note) on http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.open.php. But the best I can get it to do is to create the directory. There are no files! The Zip Archive is not empty, so I'm unsure why I'm getting this behavior. It occurs on both my local and production environment.

Here's the code:

```css
function getZip ($unitID, $zipLink) {
    // First, check to see if the LMS Asset exists in the ephemeral file system before grabbing the file from file storage
    $assetPath = "assets/".$unitID."/";
    if (file_exists($assetPath)) {
        return; 
    } else {
        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        if ($zip->open($zipLink, 0|1)===TRUE) {
            $zip->extractTo($assetPath);
            $zip->close();
        } else {
            echo "Unable to open file because of an error: ";
            echo $zip->open($zipLink);
        }
        
    }
}
```

## Update

It seems the zip->open() didn't like it if the link was pointing to a remote resource. I was able to get it to work if I pointed to a Zip file that already existed on the filesystem. Since that's not what the use case required, I had to figure out how to first get the file from the remote location, save it as a temporary file in the local filesystem, and then execute the commands. Here's the code I ended up with that works:

```
function getZip ($unitID, $zipLink) {
// Before doing anything, check to see if the file exists.
$assetPath = "assets/".$unitID."/index.html";
if (file_exists($assetPath)) {
    echo "The file already exists!";
    return;
} else {
    $path = "assets/".$unitID;
    $zipFileRemote = file_get_contents($zipLink);
    $zipFileLocal = "mytempzip".$unitID.".zip";
    file_put_contents($zipFileLocal, $zipFileRemote);
    echo "<br/>".$path;
    echo $zipLink;
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $res = $zip->open($zipFileLocal);
    if ($res===TRUE) {
        $zip->extractTo($path);
        $zip->close();
        unlink($zipFileLocal);
    } else {
        echo "There was an error: ".$res;
    }
}
```

}

I also updated the condition to check for an index.html file in the extracted file location. I don't want the function to do anything if the zip file's contents already exist on the filesystem. I can see this being an issue if the contents of the zip file on the remote change, but since this application lives on Heroku, and it uses an ephemeral filesystem, I can easily purge application-created files by restarting the dyno.

Although the above code works, I'd be interested to know if you see opportunities for improvement.

Comment: Why are you using 0|1 as a bitmask? You should be using the defined flags on the page you linked

Comment: I am very new to PHP development. When I looked at the documentation, it shows "ZipArchive::open ( string $filename [, int $flags ] )" which led me to believe the flags had to be ints. Also when I typed the name of the flags, my IDE underlined it in red so I assumed it was wrong. I'll try typing the flag names and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this line is your issue.

```
$assetPath = "assets/".$unitID."/";
if (file_exists($assetPath)) {
    return; 
}else{
    //....
}
```

Should be `if(!file_exists($assetPath))`, or in English `If not file or dir exists, do this`, with the "Bang(!)"

The function `file_exists` checks both files and dirs, so you are saying if the dir exists then `return`.  Therefore, it never runs what is in the `else` block and never extracts the files.  It's not unexpected though, its doing exactly what you told it to do.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

> **file_exists** — Checks whether a file or directory exists

In any case I wouldn't suggest doing a return, it would be better to throw an exception, or otherwise output something.  Than this would be clear.  So something like this:

```
if (!file_exists($assetPath)) {
    throw new Exception("Directory ".dirname($assetPath)." does not exist"); 
}else{
```

This is just a simple "Logic" error, no biggie.

One last thing is personally I would use `is_dir` and not `file_exists`. I would say this can actually avoid some issues if you accidentally pass in the filename.  But because you are adding the `/` after it, that probably wont happen.  So we can chuck it up to "Readability"

**UPDATE**
To check if a folder is empty, which is really what you want (I also added mkdir to created the folder, but this is optional)

```
$assetPath = "assets/".$unitID."/"
if(is_dir($assetPath)){
    $contents = array_diff(scandir($assetPath), ['.','..']); //remove . and .. 
    if(empty($contents)) return;
}else{
    mkdir($assetPath, 0755, true); //recursive [optional]
}

//obviously if it returned we wouldn't be here...

$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open($zipLink, 0|1)===TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo($assetPath);
    $zip->close();
} else {
    echo "Unable to open file because of an error: ";
    echo $zip->open($zipLink);
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! I actually do want the function to stop and return to the calling function if the file exists on the file system, because there's no need to fetch the file from the internet and unzip it again. That being said, I commented out that block to isolate the issue. I'm still having the issue where it's creating the folders in the file system but not extracting the actual files.

Comment: `if the file exists`  Unfortunately for you, this is not a file `$assetPath = "assets/".$unitID."/";`  Further, in order to check that what you really want to check is if the folder is empty,which you can do with `scandir`

Comment: `I'm still having the issue where it's creating the folders in the file system but not extracting the actual files`  this makes no sense, because you are not creating the folder in any of the code you have show, so why don't you share the actual code.  Besides, I am 100% sure that once it finds the folder and does the return it will not run the Zip stuff...

Comment: For the flag names, it's better to use them.  These are `constants` in php, which in turn (for these) are ints.  But it's neither here nor there, it should work either way.  The reason to use the constants is if they were to change the value of it in a future release of PHP it would not break.

Comment: I made an update to my original post; I've been able to get the code to work by first ensuring the Zip file from the remote resource is saved as a temporary file in the location where the script is running.

Comment: That may be but you changed this `$assetPath = "assets/".$unitID."/index.html";`  because that (before changing it) was preventing it from ever getting to the Zip (as I said), what happens after that is irrelvant to me/or this question in general, just saying.